# Puppeteer - counting elements by class name

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get info about all the elements with a particular class name into an array.

The problem is this is a dynamically generated HTML page, and as long as I scroll down, new elements of that class name appear.

Fortunately, I know beforehand how many of these elements exist.

So my hypothetical solution is to check the number of elements with that particular class name, and as long as that number is less than the one I know, keep scrolling down.

The problem is I don't know exactly how to count elements of a particular class name inside puppeteer and the API was not very useful either.

Comment: Somethig like `getElementsByClassName(".someclass").length` ?

Comment: Will this work in my case in puppeteer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function count () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
  await page.evaluate(_ => {
    window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)
  })

  console.log('how many?', (await page.$$('td.title')).length)

  await browser.close()
}

count()
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote this:
await page.evaluate(() => {
        while (await page.$$('.ftS3w _hd9n').length < counter) { 
   window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
  }
    });  But i get an error that the 'page' inside the while loop - next to await is an unexpected identifier

Comment: Did you try to scroll the element that contains the items, instead of the window?

Comment: Hi! If you want, you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709049/puppeteer-infinite-scrolling-situation. Thanks a ton!

Comment: working flawlessly, thanks!