# Puppeteer - counting elements in the DOM

Tags: jquery-selectors, puppeteer

I know this has been answered here

[Puppeteer - counting elements by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645795/puppeteer-counting-elements-by-class-name/50655303)

Yet, following this approach, I get 0 as my result

using `page.$$` - in my test, I always get 0

```
console.log((await page.$$('.clients-table > tbody > tr > td')).length);
```

verified in browser using `document.querySelectorAll()` and the result is 4

[image: html]
[image: console log in browser]

How could this be???

Comment: Your code is working for me using this page https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp. Are you sure the table is loading when you are requesting that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is not loaded yet. You can use `waitForSelector` to ensure the data is loaded properly.

So just add this before counting the numbers,

```
await page.waitForSelector('.clients-table > tbody > tr > td');
console.log((await page.$$('.clients-table > tbody > tr > td')).length);
```

Also you can make sure the page is fully loaded using `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` argument.