# Count years with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I'm trying to count the total number of "year" from the following page:
See **UPDATE** below.

In my Nodejs script, I have:

```
await page.click(SELECT_YEARS_TO_VIEW);
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
    page.waitForSelector('#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td.DataItemSelections')
]);
const numberOfYears = (await page.$$('#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td.DataItemSelections')).length;

console.log(`Years length: ${numberOfYears}.`);
```

It returns: Years length: 16.

Instead, in the  Chrome console, if I run:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td.DataItemSelections').length;
```

The (correct) output is: 39

I have read [Puppeteer - counting elements in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168344/puppeteer-counting-elements-in-the-dom), but the suggestions inside it didn't resolve my problem.

**UPDATE:** the starting point is: https://unctadstat.unctad.org/wds/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=96740

[image]

Then you have to click the icon "Select items to view" and then to "YEAR":
[image]
Here, the page where I need to count the number of the years:
[image]

Comment: That URL is wrong. Can you check or post the HTML?

Comment: @Juan Cristóbal Olivares: sorry, I have update my question. Thanks.

Comment: Just giving another option, there seems to be a POST request going to https://unctadstat.unctad.org/wds/TableViewer/getItems.aspx?row=0&rowCount=1000&id=Dim2 (search 1970 in devtools network tab) with some formData. It returns the XML of your year records, may be you can intercept it and count the total there.

Comment: Also maybe try page.click with Promise.all after waitForNavigation as mentioned [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1412#issuecomment-345357063)

Answer (score 0):

The site is changing html based on scroll, you can open the dev tools and check the html tr tags change with the scroll, you can try and do the scroll to get the data but you can just intercept the response with all that data anyway.

Another way of counting the years,

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('response', async response => {
    if (response.url().indexOf('https://unctadstat.unctad.org/wds/TableViewer/getItems.aspx') > -1) {
      console.log(response.url());
      console.log(await response.text()); // parse xml to json and count it
    }
  })

await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
    page.click(SELECT_YEARS_TO_VIEW)
  ]);
```